# Rgraphviz neato layout

Tags: r, graphviz, neato

I'm trying to create a cluster diagram for an adjacency matrix I've constructed in R.  I can get it to render the diagram but I don't know how to modify the neato-specific parameters so the diagram doesn't look completely tangled.

here's what I have so far:

```
am.graph<-new("graphAM", adjMat=linkadj, edgemode="undirected")
plot(am.graph, "neato")
```

Between the above commands it seems like you should use the [following function](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/Rgraphviz/html/layoutGraph.html) but the documentation is too sparse for me to make sense of it